# Getting error while compiling Glib 2.36.3

Tags: configuration-files, glib, qemu

I've given the required environment variable which are given below answer I'm compiling it with following code:

```
./configure --prefix="/home/qemu/support_libs/libs/glib"

 export CFLAGS="-I`pwd`/../../support_libs/libs/gettext/include"

    export LIBFFI_CFLAGS="-I`pwd`/../../support_libs/libs/libffi/lib/libffi-3.0.13/include"

    export LIBFFI_LIBS="-L`pwd`/../../support_libs/libs/libffi/lib -lffi"

    export ZLIB_CFLAGS="-I`pwd`/../../support_libs/libs/zlib/include"

    export ZLIB_LIBS="-L`pwd`/../../support_libs/libs/zlib/lib -lz"

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="`pwd`/../../support_libs/libs/gettext/lib:`pwd`/../..    
/support_libs/libs/zlib/lib"

    LDFLAGS="-L`pwd`/../../support_libs/libs/gettext/lib"
```

I have taken care of necessary dependecy but I'm getting this error

```
You must have either have gettext support in your C library, or use the
*** GNU gettext library. (http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/gettext.htm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every thing is ok .. but the binary for which gettext is looking for(msgfmt) is in the bin directory of gettext(gettext/bin). so all we need to do is to add this bin path in PATH environment variable.

After this everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure libintl installed, and that glib can find it.

The macro to you need to satisfy is GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT, defined at https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/m4macros/glib-gettext.m4#n308